# Как настроить проброс ssh ключа в phpstorm

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, ssh-key

Есть сервер на который происходит подключение по ssh по ключу. С этого сервера нужно еще раз подключится на другой сервер по этому же ключу. Нужно настроить проброс этого ключа. И двойное соединение. Основная работа на втором сервере. Может кто-то сталкивался? Как настроить такое в phpstorm?